# How to use Spring batch CompositeItemWriter with different data and having two JdbcBatchItemWritter and in Java configurations without xml

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Below is the step code which will get initialized in job.

```
@Bean
public Step stepOne() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepOne")
            .<EmployeeDTO, EmployeeDTO> chunk(1)
            .reader(readerOne())
            .processor(processorOne())
            .writer(compositeWriter())
            .build();
}
```

Below is the composite writer for writting the data.

```
@Bean
public CompositeItemWriter<EmployeeDTO> compositeWriter(){

    return new CompositeWriter();
}

public class CompositeWriter extends CompositeItemWriter<EmployeeDTO> {

   @Autowired
   private DataSource dataSource;

   List<EmployeeDTO> insert;
   List<EmployeeDTO> update;

   @Override
   public void write(List<? extends EmployeeDTO> arg0) throws Exception {
       CompositeItemWriter<EmployeeDTO> compositeItemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
       compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(insertW(),updateW()));
   }

   private JdbcBatchItemWriter<EmployeeDTO> insertW() throws Exception{
       JdbcBatchItemWriter<EmployeeDTO> batchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
       batchItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
       batchItemWriter.setSql("");
       batchItemWriter.write(insert);
       return batchItemWriter;
   }

   private JdbcBatchItemWriter<EmployeeDTO> updateW() throws Exception{
       JdbcBatchItemWriter<EmployeeDTO> batchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
       batchItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
       batchItemWriter.setSql("");
       batchItemWriter.write(update);
       return batchItemWriter;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

There are a couple of issues with your configuration:

- You don't need to call the `write` method on the writer (`batchItemWriter.write(insert)` and `batchItemWriter.write(update)`), Spring Batch will do it.
- There is no need to subclass the `CompositeItemWriter`. You can create an instance an register delegate writers in it.
- Delegate writers need to be registered as streams in the step.

Here is how to proceed in your case:

#### 1. Define delegate writers

```
@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<EmployeeDTO> insertW() throws Exception{
   JdbcBatchItemWriter<EmployeeDTO> batchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
   batchItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
   batchItemWriter.setSql("");
   return batchItemWriter;
}

@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<EmployeeDTO> updateW() throws Exception{
   JdbcBatchItemWriter<EmployeeDTO> batchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
   batchItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
   batchItemWriter.setSql("");
   return batchItemWriter;
}
```

#### 2. Register delegates in a `CompositeItemWriter`

```
@Bean
public CompositeItemWriter<EmployeeDTO> compositeItemWriter() {
    CompositeItemWriter<EmployeeDTO> compositeItemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
    compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(insertW(), updateW()));
    return compositeItemWriter;
}
```

#### 3. Register delegates as streams in the step (if they implement ItemSteam)

```
@Bean
public Step stepOne() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepOne")
            .<EmployeeDTO, EmployeeDTO> chunk(1)
            .reader(readerOne())
            .processor(processorOne())
            .writer(compositeItemWriter())
            .stream(insertW())
            .stream(updateW())
            .build();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Mahmoud Ben Hassine for replying. 
Could you please tell me how to pass below lists to delegates from above examples

 List<EmployeeDTO> insert;
  List<EmployeeDTO> update;

Comment: What happend if one of writers is fail (exception). Does the other is success (committed) or I 'll rollback?

Comment: The composite is a chain of writers, if one of them fails, subsequent writers won't be called, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/d8fc58338d3b059b67b5f777adc132d2564d7402/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.java#L56-L61 and the transaction will be rolled back for the composite writer.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - We've seen that if any exception arises in the first writer , then call doesn't get delegate to 2nd and 3rd writer in our case. How can we do this ? Since CompositeIteamWriter does give this facility, hence doing it using ItemStreamWriter but still no luck

Comment: JdbcBatchItemWriter does not implement ItemStream, can't use it for stream i think.. so it's a bad example

Comment: @roberttrudel the third step is optional, I edited its title by saying delegates should be registered as stream only if they implement ItemStream.

Comment: In fact you can just remove stream par t and that will work