# how to populate multiple table at a time in spring batch?

Tags: spring-batch

I am working on a project where I have to read csv files and put the data in database. I am using spring batch. But can not populate multiple table at the same time .Can anyone help me with the solve of this problem?

Comment: What is your code that you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CompositeItemWriter to write to multiple tables.  See [How to use Spring batch CompositeItemWriter with different data and having two JdbcBatchItemWritter and in Java configurations without xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53460435/how-to-use-spring-batch-compositeitemwriter-with-different-data-and-having-two-j)